# automapper-ts returns empty object using typeorm

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapping, typeorm

I'm trying to use `automapper-ts` to map from dto to entity and vice versa.
The creation of the mappings seems fine to me but when I try to map I always get an object without values.

The config:

```
        automapper
            .createMap(CityDTO, City)
            .forMember('createdBy', (opts: AutoMapperJs.IMemberConfigurationOptions) => opts.ignore())
            .forMember('createdAt', (opts: AutoMapperJs.IMemberConfigurationOptions) => opts.ignore())
            .forMember('updatedBy', (opts: AutoMapperJs.IMemberConfigurationOptions) => opts.ignore())
            .forMember('updatedAt', (opts: AutoMapperJs.IMemberConfigurationOptions) => opts.ignore());
        // These are properties present in the entity but not in the DTO
```

And this is the mapping method:

```
  const fromCityToCityDto = (source: CityDTO, destination?: City): City => {
    if (!destination) {
      destination = new City();
    }

    // This produces 'source name' and 'source population'
    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => console.log('source', key));
    // This never runs, it seems it doesn't have any key
    Object.keys(destination).forEach((key) => console.log('destination', key));

    destination = automapper.map(CityDTO, City, source);

    return destination;
  };
```

As ORM I'm using `typeorm`. This is the entity class:

```
  export class EntityBase extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ name: 'Id' })
    id: number;

    @Column({ name: 'CreatedBy', length: 50 })
    createdBy: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'CreatedAt' })
    createdAt: Date;

    @Column({ name: 'UpdatedBy', nullable: true, length: 50 })
    updatedBy: string;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: 'UpdatedAt', nullable: true })
    updatedAt: Date;
  }

  @Entity('Cities')
  export class City extends EntityBase {
    @Column({ name: 'Name', length: 50 })
    name: string;

    @Column({ name: 'Population' })
    population: number;
  }
```

EDIT: This is the result of `console.log`:

```
source id
source name
source population
source createdBy
source createdAt
source updatedBy
source updatedAt
```

Looks like the destination doesn't have any property.

Comment: You have console.logs there, would be great if youd share the result of that

Comment: I did it. I get only the source properties, The destination seems without any.

Comment: Log the destination after you executed automapper on it

Comment: The destination doesn't have any property so it doesn't log any line.
Anyway, in the `createMap` I tried to replace the classes with strings: `createMap('CityDTO', 'City') instead of `createMap(CityDTO, City)` and it works but I'm not really satisfied. Is there a way to strongly typed mappings?

Comment: I write my own mappers in constructos of DTOs so i dont know if there is any automapper working as you would love it to work

Comment: I found what is the issue. `destination` doesn't have initialized properties, so functions like `Object.keys` return an empty array.